# Laravel Class Namespacing

Tags: php, class, laravel, namespaces

I have created a few custom classes in App/ of laravel 5 as such:

App/Database.php 
App/Table.php 
App/ContactsTable.php

In my ContactsTable class, I'm extending the Table class

```
use Table;
/**
 * Description of ContactsTable
 * 
 * @author john
 */
class ContactsTable extends Table {
```

I have the aliases setup in config/app.php for Table (App\Table) and ContactsTable (App\ContactsTable). But when loading the page it gives me an error:

"The use statement with non-compound name 'Table' has no effect"

I have tried multiple combinations of importing the class in different ways, with no luck.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are currently in the same namespace as the `Table` class.  Since you also aliased it as `Table`, it probably doesn't know what `Table` you are talking about, the aliased one which is `Table` or the `Table` that currently resides in your current namespace, which both happen to also be the same thing.

Remove the alias and remove the `use` statement.  Since these classes are in the same namespace, there is no need to do either of those things.

It's also likely a very good idea to keep both un-aliased and in the `App` namespace because those are both pretty common names and might end up causing you more trouble in the future.

I just tried to recreate this and everything works fine here.  Just to be sure though, here is the code I used...

### app\ContactsTable.php

```
namespace App;

class ContactsTable extends Table {

}
```

### app\Table.php

```
namespace App;

class Table {

}
```

### routes.php

```
Route::get('test', function()
{
    $table = new \App\ContactsTable();

    echo get_class($table);
});
```

And going to `myapp.local/test`,  it outputs `App\ContactsTable`

Comment: But when I remove the use statement and just have it like:

class ContactsTable extends App\Table {

}

It still doesn't work...

Comment: You are currently in the `App` namespace so all you need to do is `extends Table`

Comment: I still get 'Class 'Table' not found'

Comment: You've namespaced both of those files with `namespace App;` ?  I've updated my answer to show what I did to get this to work.